# What is the brightness and size of Jupiter from the Galilean moons, the closest moon, and the farthest moon?

Tags: jupiter, natural-satellites, apparent-magnitude, angular-diameter, galilean-moons

From the Moon, Earth would appear 4 times larger than the Moon seen from Earth, and the magnitude of a "full earth" is around -17.

However, Jupiter from the Galilean moons appear much larger than the Earth from the Moon. What is the apparent magnitude and angular size of Jupiter from the Galilean moons and the closest / farthest moon?

Comment: [Jupiter from Io](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=YES&COMMAND=599&EPHEM_TYPE=O&CENTER=500%40501&QUANTITIES=%279%2C13%2C24%27&START_TIME=2022-Oct-1&STOP_TIME=2022-Oct-3&STEP_SIZE=1h)

Comment: The angular size is obvious from the orbit distance and the diameter of Jupiter.  The apparent magnitude is almost as easy: calculate solar irradiance at Jupiter's orbit, multiply by albedo of Jupiter, and Bob's your uncle.

Comment: I posted some tools you can use to answer this on your other question, https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/50658/how-dark-are-eclipses-of-jupiters-moon-by-the-planet/